# Reading OLE in R?

Tags: r, oledb

I'm trying to read a file that is encoded in [OLE format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding). **It isn't a Microsoft Office/common file format** that I'd be able to just find a reader for.

I'm trying to write my own reader - I have the file's specification but need the ability to open OLE storages/streams in the file.

Does anyone know of an **R** package that would assist in this (reading OLE streams)?

Comment: **bump** I just managed to read an OLE stream in python using oletools, but was wondering if R has a similar package as well (as of Feb 2022).